# Moving large size directory using rsync

Tags: partitioning, backup, rsync

I plan to move from linux o/s a directory which is mounted on SAN(offboard) to external storage for backup. The dir size is 14TB.

I do have experience moving files in/out using rsync but never done this with large size directories/files like now.

The directories are laid down in terms on year/month/days/hours hierarchy and support raw-logs for analysis.

**Problem**

So with the above told, due to resource restrictions I'm not able to move complete 14TB to external/backup storage space. The backup space I have currently is max 8 TB. So is there a command or switch / parameter i can tell rsync to only copies files to the mentioned size i.e TB only

Answer (score 0):

The option to limit file size is

```
--max-size=SIZE
```

Where SIZE is your actual file size limit, you can use KB MB or GB as your units.
I'm not sure if TB is supported, as a unit, but if you want to test your rsync command use the option:

```
--dry-run
```